# Pandas Merge and create a multi-index for duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
sessions = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
     "2018-06-30": [23,34,45,67,75],
     "2018-07-31": [32,43,45,76,57]})
leads = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
     "2018-06-30": [7,10,28,15,30],
     "2018-07-31": [7,10,28,15,30]})
```

I wanna merge the two dataframes  on ID and then create a multi-index to look like:

```
   6/30/2018      7/31/2018
ID sessions leads sessions leads
 1       23     7       32     7
 2       34    10       43    12
 3       45    28       45    30
 4       67    15       76    18
 5       75    30       57    30
```

How can I do it?

A direct `pd.merge` will create suffixes `_x`, `_y` which I do not want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `ID` in both DataFrames and then  [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for expected `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = (pd.concat([sessions.set_index('ID'), 
                 leads.set_index('ID')], 
                axis=1, 
                keys=['sessions','leads'])
      .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
      .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
      )
print(df)
```

```
   2018-06-30       2018-07-31      
     sessions leads   sessions leads
ID                                  
1          23     7         32     7
2          34    10         43    10
3          45    28         45    28
4          67    15         76    15
5          75    30         57    30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`pd.DataFrame.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html), [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) that could be applied in this case:

```
(sessions.merge(leads, on='ID', suffixes=('_sessions', '_leads'))
 .set_index('ID')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
 .pipe(lambda d: d.reindex(columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d.columns.levels[0], d.columns.levels[1]])))
 .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False]))


   2018-06-30       2018-07-31      
     sessions leads   sessions leads
ID                                  
1          23     7         32     7
2          34    10         43    10
3          45    28         45    28
4          67    15         76    15
5          75    30         57    30
```